# Center a scaled and 90 rotated <g> transform

Tags: html, css, svg, transform

How do I horisontally and vertically center a `<g>` transform that has both a `scale` + `rotate` (90 degree) values defined?

Im my example I have a 85x85mm SVG element that im trying to center towards.

If im not rotating I can center with `scale(0.25) rotate(0 42.5 42.5) translate(42.5 42.5)`

However introducing the 90degree rotation, things go wrong.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="85mm"
   height="85mm"
   viewBox="0 0 85 85">
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- TRANSFORMATION HERE-->
  <g class="svg-merge-item-wrapper" transform="scale(0.25) rotate(90 42.5 42.5) translate(42.5 42.5)">
  <!-- TRANSFORMATION HERE-->
  
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.375;stroke-miterlimit:3.9892;}
</style>
<path id="path6" class="st0" d="M119.2,35.9c0,0,11.2,0,15,7.4c3.8,7.4,4.2,17.8,4.5,19.2c0.3,1.4,0.3,6.3,6,10.8
    c5.6,4.5,6.3,18.5,6.3,18.5s1.4,0,1.4,1.7v5.2c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c0,0,0,18.5-0.4,28.7c-0.4,10.1-4.2,43-6,50
    c-1.8,7-10.5,31.9-10.5,31.9h-29.7c0,0-9.4-21.7-11.9-36.4s-5.3-24.8-5.6-39.5c-0.3-14.7,0-34.6,0-34.6s-2.1,0.3-2.1-1.4v-5.6
    c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.3-1.4c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0-12.6,4.5-16.8c4.5-4.2,6-8,6.3-9.4c0.3-1.4,0.7-7.7,0.7-7.7c1.6-2.2,2.7-4.7,3.1-7.3
    c0.7-4.2,1.1-5.6,1.1-5.6s2.8-6,5.9-7c1.7-0.6,3.5-1,5.3-1.4C115.4,36.1,117.3,35.9,119.2,35.9z"/>
<path id="path8" class="st0" d="M88.4,91.5v-0.3c0,0,0-12.1,4.3-16.1c4.3-4,5.7-7.7,6-9.1c0.2-0.9,0.4-3.9,0.6-5.8
    c0.1-1,0.4-2,0.9-2.8c1.1-1.8,1.8-3.8,2.2-5.9c0.7-4,1-5.4,1-5.4s2.7-5.7,5.6-6.7c1.6-0.6,3.3-1,5-1.3c1.8-0.2,3.5-0.3,5.3-0.3
    c0,0,10.6,0,14.3,7.1c3.7,7.1,3.7,17.5,4.1,18.8c0.4,4,2.4,7.7,5.6,10.1c5.3,4.4,6.3,17.8,6.3,17.8v0.3"/>
<path id="path10" class="st0" d="M98.2,57.6c0,0-10.5-15-15.7-17.5s-11.9-4.5-10.8-6.6c0,0,7-2.1,18.5,4.5s12.1,7.4,12.1,7.4"/>
<path id="path12" class="st0" d="M107,38.4c0,0-0.1-1.8-1.5-1.8c-1.4,0-2.4,1-5.6,0c-3.2-1-3.1-1.4-3.5-1.4
    c-0.3,0-14.3-6.6-18.2-6.6s-6.3,0-7,2.1c-0.7,2.1,0,2.7,0,2.7l0.3,0.1"/>
<circle id="circle14" class="st0" cx="112.2" cy="44.3" r="1.4"/>
<circle id="circle16" class="st0" cx="111.8" cy="44" r="0.7"/>
<line id="line18" class="st0" x1="86.6" y1="91.5" x2="151" y2="91.9"/>
<line id="line20" class="st0" x1="151.3" y1="99.9" x2="87.3" y2="99.9"/>
<path id="path22" class="st0" d="M151.2,118.6c0,0,1.5,0.5,1.5-1.6v-9.8c0,0-0.3-2.1,3.8-1.4c4.2,0.7,9.4,2.1,10.8,8.4
    c0.8,3.8,1,7.7,0.8,11.6c-0.1,1.6-0.2,3.2-0.5,4.8c-1,5.3-3.1,16.6-7.5,24.5c-4.1,7.2-13.5,20.9-17.5,30.9"/>
<path id="path24" class="st0" d="M151.3,104.8c0,0,2-1.4,5.9-0.6c4.2,0.9,10.1,2.4,11.8,9.6c1.6,6.5,0.9,11.6,0.2,16.7
    c-0.7,4.7-1.7,9.3-3.1,13.8c-0.9,2.9-3.4,9.8-5.8,13.6c-1.3,2-13.6,21.7-16.1,27.9s-3.5,8-3.5,16.8c0,7.3,2.8,7.7,2.8,7.7h-2.1
    c0,0-4.6-6.2-1.1-17.2"/>
<path id="path26" class="st0" d="M113.2,105.1h11.5c4.6,5.4,5.2,13.1,1.7,19.2c-6,10.8-6.3,7.3-7,16.8c-0.6,7.9,1.5,17,2.2,19.8
    c0.3,1,0.3,2,0.2,3c-0.3,2.3-1.9,4.7-8-1.4c-7.7-7.7-8.6-23.2-8.7-27.8c0-0.8,0.1-1.7,0.2-2.5c0.9-4.3,2.4-8.5,4.3-12.4
    C112.9,113.9,113.2,105.5,113.2,105.1z"/>
<path id="path28" class="st0" d="M104.8,210.4H93.7c-0.4,0.3-0.5,1-0.2,1.4c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.3c1.4,0.7,51.7-0.3,51.7-0.3
    c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4h-11.2"/>
<polyline id="polyline30" class="st0" points="113.1,106.9 125.8,106.9 126,106.8 "/>
<line id="line32" class="st0" x1="118" y1="165.8" x2="121.1" y2="165.8"/>
<line id="line34" class="st0" x1="116.6" y1="164.8" x2="121.7" y2="164.8"/>
<line id="line36" class="st0" x1="121.9" y1="163.9" x2="115.5" y2="163.9"/>
<line id="line38" class="st0" x1="114.5" y1="163.1" x2="122" y2="163.1"/>
<line id="line40" class="st0" x1="122" y1="162.1" x2="113.6" y2="162.1"/>
<line id="line42" class="st0" x1="112.6" y1="161" x2="121.7" y2="161"/>
<polyline id="polyline44" class="st0" points="112.9,108.5 126.9,108.5 127,108.5 "/>
<polyline id="polyline46" class="st0" points="112.6,110.1 127.5,110.1 127.6,110.1 "/>
<polyline id="polyline48" class="st0" points="112.4,111.6 127.9,111.6 128.1,111.6 "/>
<line id="line50" class="st0" x1="111.6" y1="114.8" x2="128.7" y2="114.8"/>
<line id="line52" class="st0" x1="128.8" y1="116.4" x2="111.2" y2="116.4"/>
<line id="line54" class="st0" x1="110.5" y1="118.3" x2="114.6" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line56" class="st0" x1="115" y1="118.3" x2="116" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line58" class="st0" x1="117" y1="118.3" x2="125.5" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line60" class="st0" x1="125.8" y1="118.3" x2="128.6" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line62" class="st0" x1="114.2" y1="120.3" x2="115.2" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line64" class="st0" x1="116.2" y1="120.3" x2="121.3" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line66" class="st0" x1="122.1" y1="120.3" x2="124.1" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line68" class="st0" x1="124.6" y1="120.3" x2="125.8" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line70" class="st0" x1="126.7" y1="120.3" x2="127.5" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line72" class="st0" x1="109.5" y1="120.3" x2="113.6" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line74" class="st0" x1="106.6" y1="127.7" x2="124.6" y2="127.7"/>
<polyline id="polyline76" class="st0" points="128.5,113.2 128.2,113.2 112,113.2 "/>
<ellipse id="ellipse78" class="st0" cx="113.4" cy="44.7" rx="4.7" ry="3.8"/>
<path id="path80" class="st0" d="M123.4,125.9l2.2,0.1"/>
<path id="path82" class="st0" d="M119.3,125.8h2.4"/>
<path id="path84" class="st0" d="M116.4,125.8h1.5"/>
<path id="path86" class="st0" d="M112.5,125.9h2.4"/>
<path id="path88" class="st0" d="M109.6,125.9h1.4"/>
<path id="path90" class="st0" d="M107.2,125.9h1.1"/>
<path id="path92" class="st0" d="M107.5,129.4h-1.3"/>
<path id="path94" class="st0" d="M110.6,129.3h-1.8"/>
<path id="path96" class="st0" d="M116.1,129.3h-4.1"/>
<path id="path98" class="st0" d="M123.6,129.4c-2,0-4-0.1-6.1-0.1"/>
<line id="line100" class="st0" x1="105.7" y1="131.1" x2="122.4" y2="131.1"/>
<path id="path102" class="st0" d="M107.5,132.8h-2.1"/>
<path id="path104" class="st0" d="M113.7,132.8h-4.9"/>
<path id="path106" class="st0" d="M121.3,132.8h-6.2"/>
<path id="path108" class="st0" d="M107.7,134.5h-2.5"/>
<path id="path110" class="st0" d="M114.4,134.5h-5.3"/>
<path id="path112" class="st0" d="M120.5,134.5h-4.6"/>
<line id="line114" class="st0" x1="105.2" y1="136.2" x2="120" y2="136.2"/>
<path id="path116" class="st0" d="M117.2,137.9h2.6"/>
<path id="path118" class="st0" d="M111.7,137.9h3.8"/>
<path id="path120" class="st0" d="M105.3,137.9h5"/>
<line id="line122" class="st0" x1="119.7" y1="139.3" x2="105.4" y2="139.3"/>
<line id="line124" class="st0" x1="105.6" y1="140.7" x2="119.6" y2="140.7"/>
<line id="line126" class="st0" x1="119.5" y1="141.9" x2="105.8" y2="141.9"/>
<line id="line128" class="st0" x1="105.9" y1="143.2" x2="119.4" y2="143.2"/>
<line id="line130" class="st0" x1="119.4" y1="144.4" x2="106.1" y2="144.4"/>
<path id="path132" class="st0" d="M114.1,145.6h5.4"/>
<path id="path134" class="st0" d="M109.4,145.6h2.9"/>
<path id="path136" class="st0" d="M106.3,145.7h1.8"/>
<line id="line138" class="st0" x1="111.7" y1="159.8" x2="121.4" y2="159.7"/>
<line id="line140" class="st0" x1="121.2" y1="158.5" x2="110.9" y2="158.5"/>
<line id="line142" class="st0" x1="110.2" y1="157.3" x2="120.9" y2="157.3"/>
<line id="line144" class="st0" x1="109.6" y1="156.2" x2="120.7" y2="156.2"/>
<line id="line146" class="st0" x1="109.1" y1="154.9" x2="120.4" y2="154.9"/>
<line id="line148" class="st0" x1="120.2" y1="153.5" x2="108.5" y2="153.5"/>
<line id="line150" class="st0" x1="107.9" y1="152" x2="120" y2="152"/>
<line id="line152" class="st0" x1="107.6" y1="150.7" x2="119.8" y2="150.7"/>
<line id="line154" class="st0" x1="119.7" y1="149.2" x2="107.1" y2="149.2"/>
<path id="path156" class="st0" d="M115.5,148h4.1"/>
<path id="path158" class="st0" d="M110.7,148h3.3"/>
<path id="path160" class="st0" d="M106.8,148h2.4"/>
<line id="line162" class="st0" x1="119.5" y1="146.8" x2="106.6" y2="146.8"/>
<path id="path164" class="st0" d="M114.3,92.7h1.7"/>
<path id="path166" class="st0" d="M106.3,92.6c2.1,0,4.2,0,6.3,0"/>
<path id="path168" class="st0" d="M98.2,92.6h6.6"/>
<path id="path170" class="st0" d="M91.7,92.7l4.9-0.1"/>
<path id="path172" class="st0" d="M85.3,92.7h5"/>
<path id="path174" class="st0" d="M130,92.7h-5"/>
<path id="path176" class="st0" d="M136.5,92.6l-4.8,0.1"/>
<path id="path178" class="st0" d="M137.8,92.6c4.7,0,9.5,0,14.2,0.1h0.2"/>
<line id="line180" class="st0" x1="86.6" y1="99.9" x2="86.6" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line182" class="st0" x1="88.9" y1="99.9" x2="88.9" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line184" class="st0" x1="91.1" y1="99.9" x2="91.1" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path186" class="st0" d="M93.3,94.3v-1.1"/>
<path id="path188" class="st0" d="M93.3,99.9v-4.4"/>
<path id="path190" class="st0" d="M95.6,95.4v-2.1"/>
<path id="path192" class="st0" d="M95.6,99.9v-3"/>
<line id="line194" class="st0" x1="97.8" y1="99.9" x2="97.8" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line196" class="st0" x1="100" y1="99.9" x2="100" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line198" class="st0" x1="102.2" y1="99.9" x2="102.2" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path200" class="st0" d="M104.5,94.7v-1.5"/>
<path id="path202" class="st0" d="M104.5,99.9V96"/>
<path id="path204" class="st0" d="M106.7,95.2v-1.9"/>
<path id="path206" class="st0" d="M106.7,99.9v-3"/>
<path id="path208" class="st0" d="M108.9,94.7v-1.5"/>
<path id="path210" class="st0" d="M108.9,97.5v-1.7"/>
<path id="path212" class="st0" d="M108.9,99.9v-1.2"/>
<path id="path214" class="st0" d="M111.1,94.3v-1.1"/>
<path id="path216" class="st0" d="M111.1,99.6v-1.1"/>
<path id="path218" class="st0" d="M126.9,94.8v-1.6"/>
<path id="path220" class="st0" d="M126.9,99.9v-1.6"/>
<path id="path222" class="st0" d="M129.1,94.5v-1.3"/>
<path id="path224" class="st0" d="M129.1,97.3v-1.2"/>
<path id="path226" class="st0" d="M129.1,99.9v-1.4"/>
<path id="path228" class="st0" d="M131.3,94.4v-1.2"/>
<path id="path230" class="st0" d="M131.3,96.9v-1.2"/>
<path id="path232" class="st0" d="M131.3,99.9v-1.8"/>
<path id="path234" class="st0" d="M133.5,94.8v-1.6"/>
<path id="path236" class="st0" d="M133.5,99.9v-2.6"/>
<path id="path238" class="st0" d="M135.7,94.5v-1.3"/>
<path id="path240" class="st0" d="M135.7,96.8v-1.2"/>
<path id="path242" class="st0" d="M135.7,99.9V98"/>
<path id="path244" class="st0" d="M138,95.1v-1.8"/>
<path id="path246" class="st0" d="M138,99.9v-3.6"/>
<line id="line248" class="st0" x1="140.2" y1="99.9" x2="140.2" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line250" class="st0" x1="142.4" y1="99.9" x2="142.4" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line252" class="st0" x1="144.6" y1="99.9" x2="144.6" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line254" class="st0" x1="146.9" y1="99.9" x2="146.9" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line256" class="st0" x1="149.1" y1="99.9" x2="149.1" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line258" class="st0" x1="151" y1="99.9" x2="151" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path260" class="st0" d="M142.3,211.3c1.2,0,2.4,0,3.7,0.1"/>
<path id="path262" class="st0" d="M136.5,211.4h2.9"/>
<path id="path264" class="st0" d="M131.9,211.5l3.4-0.1"/>
<path id="path266" class="st0" d="M111.2,211.8c1.9,0,3.7,0,5.6,0"/>
<path id="path268" class="st0" d="M93.5,211.8h13"/>
<path id="path270" class="st0" d="M114.8,47.7c1.7-0.3,2.9-2,2.6-3.7"/>
<path id="path272" class="st0" d="M112.2,47.8c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0"/>
<path id="path274" class="st0" d="M71,32.1c0,0,11.2-1.5,19.4,6"/>
<path id="path276" class="st0" d="M106.5,37.1c-2.3,1-3.6,3.4-3.2,5.9"/>
<path id="path278" class="st0" d="M79.8,28.8c0,0,16,6.4,17.7,7.5c1.7,1.1,4.9,1.7,6,1.4c0.8-0.2,1.6-0.4,2.5-0.4"/>
<path id="path280" class="st0" d="M75.4,28.6c3.5,0.7,6.9,1.9,10.2,3.5c4.9,2.5,11.5,5.2,11.5,5.2s4.5,2.1,6,1.4
    c1.4-0.7,1.8-0.6,1.8-0.6"/>
<path id="path282" class="st0" d="M72.5,29.2c0,0,2.9-0.3,7.8,1.8c4.9,2.1,16.8,7.7,16.8,7.7s4.2,1.8,5.2,1.1
    c0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.7-0.7"/>
<path id="path284" class="st0" d="M81,32.3c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.4,1.8,0.5"/>
<path id="path286" class="st0" d="M76.9,30.9c1,0.3,2,0.7,3,1.1"/>
<path id="path288" class="st0" d="M71.5,30.3c1.4-0.3,2.9-0.3,4.3,0.2"/>
<path id="path290" class="st0" d="M71.6,34.4c0,0,9.4,2.9,12.6,5.7c3.1,2.8,14.8,15.1,14.5,16.7"/>
<path id="path292" class="st0" d="M99.6,55.3c0,0-13-15.5-17.5-17.6c-4.6-2.1-9.8-4.3-9.8-4.3"/>
<path id="path294" class="st0" d="M88.7,41.6c4.2,3.8,7.8,8.3,11.5,12.6"/>
<path id="path296" class="st0" d="M83.9,37.9c0.9,0.6,1.7,1.2,2.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path298" class="st0" d="M81.4,36.3c0.5,0.3,1,0.5,1.4,0.8"/>
<path id="path300" class="st0" d="M74.9,33.2c1.1,0.5,2.1,1,3.2,1.5"/>
<path id="path302" class="st0" d="M91.8,43.5c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.3-1.2"/>
<path id="path304" class="st0" d="M95.1,46.9c-0.8-0.9-1.6-1.7-2.4-2.6"/>
<path id="path306" class="st0" d="M97.8,49.8l-1.1-1.2"/>
<path id="path308" class="st0" d="M100.6,52.9l-2.1-2.3"/>
<path id="path310" class="st0" d="M106.8,37.6c0,0-2.8,1.5-2.7,4.1"/>
<polyline id="polyline312" class="st0" points="124.1,99.9 124.1,103.8 124.1,105.1 "/>
<line id="line314" class="st0" x1="127.2" y1="99.9" x2="127.2" y2="109.3"/>
<path id="path316" class="st0" d="M123,150.1c0,1,0,1.9,0,2.9"/>
<path id="path318" class="st0" d="M123.1,146.3c0,0.8-0.1,1.6-0.1,2.4"/>
<path id="path320" class="st0" d="M123.3,142.7c0,0.6,0,1.1-0.1,1.7"/>
<path id="path322" class="st0" d="M123.6,135.6c-0.1,1.7-0.2,3.3-0.3,5"/>
<path id="path324" class="st0" d="M123.9,128.8l-0.2,5.5"/>
<path id="path326" class="st0" d="M124.9,169.2c0,0.6-0.1,1.1-0.2,1.7"/>
<path id="path328" class="st0" d="M125.2,165.8c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.1,1.4"/>
<path id="path330" class="st0" d="M125.5,161.2c0,0.6-0.1,1.1-0.1,1.7"/>
<path id="path332" class="st0" d="M125.8,155.6c0,1.1-0.1,2.3-0.2,3.4"/>
<path id="path334" class="st0" d="M126.1,148.6c0,1-0.1,2.1-0.2,3.1"/>
<path id="path336" class="st0" d="M126.7,139.7c-0.2,2-0.3,4-0.4,6"/>
<path id="path338" class="st0" d="M126.8,135.3c0,1,0,2-0.1,2.9"/>
<path id="path340" class="st0" d="M127,123.5c-0.1,3.3-0.1,6.5-0.1,10.1"/>
<path id="path342" class="st0" d="M124.8,180.5c-0.1,0.6-0.3,1.3-0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path344" class="st0" d="M125.6,177.2c-0.1,0.6-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path346" class="st0" d="M128,159.2c-0.6,5.7-1.3,11.3-2.3,17"/>
<path id="path348" class="st0" d="M130.3,99.9c-0.2,14.5-0.3,29-1.1,43.5c-0.2,4.1-0.5,8.3-0.9,12.4"/>
<path id="path350" class="st0" d="M125.4,185c-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.5-0.6,2.3"/>
<path id="path352" class="st0" d="M126.8,180.5c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.9-0.9,2.8"/>
<path id="path354" class="st0" d="M129.1,167.6c-0.4,3.8-1.1,7.6-2,11.4"/>
<path id="path356" class="st0" d="M132.1,99.9c0,21.7,0,43.3-2.7,64.8"/>
<path id="path358" class="st0" d="M126.2,189.9c-0.1,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.4,1.6"/>
<path id="path360" class="st0" d="M127.1,186.4c-0.1,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path362" class="st0" d="M129.7,173.7c-0.5,3.1-1.1,6.1-1.8,9.2"/>
<path id="path364" class="st0" d="M133.9,99.9c-0.4,23.1-0.8,46.1-3.5,69.1"/>
<path id="path366" class="st0" d="M127.3,192.5c-0.2,1-0.5,2.1-0.8,3.1"/>
<path id="path368" class="st0" d="M135.7,99.9c-0.5,30.4-0.8,61.2-8,90.8"/>
<path id="path370" class="st0" d="M127.1,198c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.3,1.2"/>
<path id="path372" class="st0" d="M128,194.8c-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4"/>
<path id="path374" class="st0" d="M137.5,99.9c-0.9,31.1-0.5,62.6-9,92.5"/>
<path id="path376" class="st0" d="M128.7,197.7c-0.3,1.1-0.5,2.1-0.8,3.2"/>
<path id="path378" class="st0" d="M139.3,99.9c-0.6,16.1,0.1,32.2-2,48.6v3.5c-1.4,15-3.8,30.1-8.2,44.2"/>
<path id="path380" class="st0" d="M141.2,99.9c0,0-0.3,25.4-1,37.3c-0.6,9.1-2.7,31.8-5.3,42.3c-2.2,8.6-6,21.9-6.6,24.3"/>
<path id="path382" class="st0" d="M143,99.9c0,0-0.4,27.2-1.1,38c-0.6,8.6-3,32.8-5.8,43c-2.4,8.8-7.4,25.1-7.8,27"/>
<path id="path384" class="st0" d="M144.8,99.9c0,0-0.4,28.9-1.2,38.7c-0.6,8.1-3.3,33.8-6.3,43.8c-2.7,9-6.3,20.9-6.7,22.4l-1.7,5.5
    "/>
<path id="path386" class="st0" d="M146.6,99.9c0,0-0.5,30.7-1.2,39.5c-0.6,7.6-3.6,34.7-6.7,44.6c-3,9.1-6.9,21.8-7.1,22.7
    c0,0-1,3.3-1.1,3.7"/>
<path id="path388" class="st0" d="M148.4,99.9c0,0-0.6,32.5-1.3,40.2c-0.7,7.2-3.9,35.7-7.2,45.4c-3.2,9.3-7.4,22.6-7.5,23.1
    l-0.6,1.8"/>
<path id="path390" class="st0" d="M150.2,99.9c0,0-0.7,34.3-1.4,40.9c-0.7,6.6-4.2,36.7-7.7,46.1c-3.5,9.4-8,23.4-8,23.4"/>
<path id="path392" class="st0" d="M114.2,180.4c0.1,0.6,0.3,1.2,0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path394" class="st0" d="M113.5,177.1c0.1,0.6,0.2,1.3,0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path396" class="st0" d="M111.1,160.1c0.6,5.3,1.3,10.6,2.2,16"/>
<path id="path398" class="st0" d="M108.7,99.9c0.1,6.8,0.2,13.5,0.4,20.3"/>
<path id="path400" class="st0" d="M113.6,184.9c0.2,0.8,0.4,1.5,0.6,2.3"/>
<path id="path402" class="st0" d="M112.3,180.4c0.3,0.9,0.5,1.9,0.9,2.8"/>
<path id="path404" class="st0" d="M109.9,167.5c0.4,3.8,1.1,7.6,2,11.4"/>
<path id="path406" class="st0" d="M108.5,154.3c0.3,3.5,0.7,6.9,1.1,10.4"/>
<path id="path408" class="st0" d="M106.6,99.9c0,8.6,0.4,17,0.5,25.6"/>
<path id="path410" class="st0" d="M112.8,189.8c0.1,0.5,0.3,1.1,0.4,1.6c0,0,1,5,1.4,7.1"/>
<path id="path412" class="st0" d="M112,186.3c0.1,0.6,0.3,1.2,0.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path414" class="st0" d="M109.3,173.6c0.5,3.1,1.1,6.1,1.8,9.2"/>
<path id="path416" class="st0" d="M106.8,148.3c0.5,6.9,1.1,13.7,1.9,20.5"/>
<path id="path418" class="st0" d="M104.8,99.9c0.2,9.6,0.6,19.2,0.9,28.8"/>
<path id="path420" class="st0" d="M111.7,192.4c0.2,1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.1"/>
<path id="path422" class="st0" d="M103.1,99.9c0.5,30.4,1,61.1,8.2,90.8"/>
<path id="path424" class="st0" d="M111.9,197.9c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3,1.2c0,0,0.7,2.9,1,4"/>
<path id="path426" class="st0" d="M111.1,194.7l0.3,1.4"/>
<path id="path428" class="st0" d="M101.3,99.9c0.9,31.1,0.7,62.5,9.1,92.4"/>
<path id="path430" class="st0" d="M110.3,197.6c0.3,1.1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.2c0,0,1.7,6,2.1,6.4"/>
<path id="path432" class="st0" d="M99.6,99.9c0.6,16.1,0,32.1,2.1,48.5v3.5c1.4,15.1,3.8,30,8.2,44.2"/>
<path id="path434" class="st0" d="M97.5,99.9c0,0,0.7,25.3,1.4,37.2c0.6,9.1,2.7,31.8,5.3,42.3c2.2,8.6,7.3,27.2,8.3,29.3"/>
<path id="path436" class="st0" d="M96.1,99.9c0,0,0.3,27.1,1.1,37.9c0.6,8.6,3,32.8,5.8,43c2.4,8.8,7.4,25.1,7.8,27"/>
<path id="path438" class="st0" d="M94.3,99.9c0,0,0.3,28.8,1.1,38.6c0.6,8.1,3.3,33.8,6.3,43.8c2.7,9,6.3,20.9,6.7,22.4l1.7,5.5v0.1
    "/>
<path id="path440" class="st0" d="M92.2,99.9c0,0,0.7,30.6,1.4,39.4c0.6,7.6,3.6,34.7,6.7,44.6c3,9.1,6.9,21.8,7.1,22.7
    c0,0,1,3.3,1.1,3.7l0.1,0.1"/>
<path id="path442" class="st0" d="M90.5,99.9c0,0,0.7,32.4,1.4,40.1c0.7,7.1,3.9,35.7,7.2,45.4c3.2,9.3,7.4,22.6,7.5,23.1l0.6,1.8
    l0.1,0.1"/>
<path id="path444" class="st0" d="M88.8,99.9c0,0,0.7,34.2,1.4,40.8c0.7,6.6,4.2,36.7,7.7,46.1s8,23.4,8,23.4"/>
<line id="line446" class="st0" x1="105.8" y1="210.2" x2="105.9" y2="210.4"/>
<path id="path448" class="st0" d="M110.6,110.3c-0.1,1,0,2,0.2,2.9"/>
<path id="path450" class="st0" d="M110.7,105c0,1,0,2.1,0,3.1"/>
<path id="path452" class="st0" d="M110.8,99.9c0,0.9,0,1.8-0.1,2.7"/>
<path id="path454" class="st0" d="M112.5,39.6c1.7-0.4,3.5-0.5,5.2-0.5c0,0,10.8-0.8,14.7,6.6c3.9,7.4,3.5,17.2,3.8,18.5
    c0.3,1.3,0.1,5.5,5.3,9.7s5.9,17.2,5.9,17.2v0.3"/>
<path id="path456" class="st0" d="M118.6,40.4c4.7,0.3,9.1,1.3,11.8,5.4c3.1,4.7,3.9,11.4,4.4,16.8c0.3,3.2,0.8,6.4,2.6,9.1"/>
<path id="path458" class="st0" d="M118.9,42.5c4.3,0.3,8.3,1.3,10.8,5.1c2.9,4.3,3.6,10.5,4,15.5c0.3,2.9,0.7,5.9,2.4,8.4"/>
<path id="path460" class="st0" d="M119.2,44.6c3.9,0.3,7.4,1.2,9.7,4.7c2.6,4,3.3,9.7,3.7,14.2c0.3,2.7,0.7,5.4,2.2,7.7"/>
<path id="path462" class="st0" d="M119.5,46.8c3.4,0.2,6.6,1.2,8.6,4.4c2.3,3.6,2.9,8.8,3.3,13c0.2,2.5,0.6,5,2,7"/>
<path id="path464" class="st0" d="M119.8,48.9c3,0.2,5.8,1.2,7.6,4.1c2,3.3,2.6,7.9,3,11.6c0.1,2.2,0.7,4.4,1.8,6.3"/>
<path id="path466" class="st0" d="M120.1,51.1c2.7,0,5.2,1.5,6.5,3.8c1.7,3,2.2,7.1,2.6,10.4c0.1,2,0.6,3.9,1.6,5.6"/>
<path id="path468" class="st0" d="M124.6,55.1c1.9,1.9,2.6,4.9,3,7.5s0.3,5.8,1.9,8.1"/>
<path id="path470" class="st0" d="M120.4,53.2c0.9,0.1,1.7,0.3,2.5,0.6"/>
<path id="path472" class="st0" d="M127,66.6c0.1,1.4,0.5,2.7,1.2,3.9"/>
<path id="path474" class="st0" d="M120.7,55.3c4.4,0.3,5.5,5.5,6,9.1"/>
<path id="path476" class="st0" d="M121,57.5c1.3,0.1,2.5,1,3.4,2.9c0.8,2.1,1.3,4.3,1.5,6.5c0.1,1.2,0.4,2.4,1.1,3.4"/>
<path id="path478" class="st0" d="M123.7,62.4c0.4,1.3,0.7,2.6,0.9,4c0,1.3,0.4,2.6,1,3.7"/>
<path id="path480" class="st0" d="M121.3,59.6c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.4,1.4,0.9"/>
<path id="path482" class="st0" d="M123.6,67.8c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.5,0.7,2.2"/>
<path id="path484" class="st0" d="M121.6,61.8c1.1,0.4,1.4,3,1.6,4"/>
<path id="path486" class="st0" d="M122.4,67.8c0,0.7,0.3,1.4,0.6,2"/>
<path id="path488" class="st0" d="M122,63.9c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.2,2"/>
<path id="path490" class="st0" d="M141.7,76.1c3.5,4.3,4.3,10.1,4.7,15.5"/>
<path id="path492" class="st0" d="M140.4,77.2c3.2,3.9,4,9.2,4.3,14.4"/>
<path id="path494" class="st0" d="M139.1,78.4c2.9,3.5,3.7,8.3,4,13.3"/>
<path id="path496" class="st0" d="M137.8,79.5c2.6,3.1,3.3,7.5,3.6,12.2"/>
<path id="path498" class="st0" d="M136.5,80.6c2.2,2.7,3,6.6,3.2,11.1"/>
<path id="path500" class="st0" d="M135.2,81.7c1.9,2.4,2.7,5.7,2.8,10"/>
<path id="path502" class="st0" d="M134,82.8c1.6,2,2.4,4.8,2.4,8.9"/>
<path id="path504" class="st0" d="M132.7,83.9c1.3,1.6,2,4,2.1,7.8"/>
<path id="path506" class="st0" d="M132.9,89.2c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.7,0.1,2.5"/>
<path id="path508" class="st0" d="M131.4,85c0.5,0.6,0.8,1.3,1.1,2"/>
<path id="path510" class="st0" d="M130.1,86.2c0.6,0.8,1.4,2.2,1.3,5.6"/>
<path id="path512" class="st0" d="M129.7,90.6c0,0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1"/>
<path id="path514" class="st0" d="M128.8,87.3c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.6,1.3"/>
<path id="path516" class="st0" d="M128.1,90c0,0.6,0,1.2,0,1.7"/>
<path id="path518" class="st0" d="M127.6,88.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1"/>
<path id="path520" class="st0" d="M98.2,70.8c0.9-1.3,1.6-2.6,2.1-4.1c0.3-2.4,0-5.2,1-7.7c1.8-4.2,2.5-8.7,3.8-13
    c0.4-1.1,1.1-2.2,2.1-2.9"/>
<path id="path522" class="st0" d="M106.9,46.7c-1,1.7-1.3,3.9-1.8,5.8c-0.5,2.1-1.1,4.2-1.8,6.3c-0.7,2-1.1,4.2-1.2,6.3
    c-0.2,2-0.9,3.9-2,5.6"/>
<path id="path524" class="st0" d="M108,48.6c-1.4,2.4-1.4,5.5-2.1,8.3c-1.4,3.5-1.7,7.3-2.8,11.2c-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-1,2.4"/>
<path id="path526" class="st0" d="M109.7,49.8c-0.6,0.6-1,1.4-1.2,2.3c-0.7,3-1.3,6.6-2.4,9.6c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6
    c-0.3,1.4-0.2,2.8-0.4,4.1c-0.2,1.1-0.6,2.1-1.2,3.1"/>
<path id="path528" class="st0" d="M108.5,59.4c-0.4,1.9-1.2,3.7-1.4,5.6c-0.3,1.9-0.2,3.7-1.1,5.3"/>
<path id="path530" class="st0" d="M110.5,52c-1.2,1-1.2,3.6-1.5,5"/>
<path id="path532" class="st0" d="M111.3,54.3c-0.4,0.5-0.6,1.2-0.6,1.8c-0.3,2.5-0.8,4.9-1.4,7.4c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.3,1.2
    c-0.2,1-0.4,2.1-0.4,3.1c-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.6-0.5,2.4"/>
<path id="path534" class="st0" d="M111.5,60.7c-1,2.9-1,6-1.6,9.3"/>
<path id="path536" class="st0" d="M112.1,56.4c-0.3,0.7-0.4,1.5-0.4,2.3"/>
<path id="path538" class="st0" d="M111.8,67.7c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.5,0,2.2"/>
<path id="path540" class="st0" d="M112.7,62.7c-0.1,1-0.3,2-0.5,3"/>
<path id="path542" class="st0" d="M112.9,58.7c0,0.7,0,1.3,0,2"/>
<path id="path544" class="st0" d="M90.2,91.5C89.8,85.2,90.8,78.2,96,74"/>
<path id="path546" class="st0" d="M92.2,91.5c-0.3-5.6,0.6-12.1,5.3-15.9"/>
<path id="path548" class="st0" d="M94.2,91.5c-0.3-4.9,0.4-10.9,4.6-14.3"/>
<path id="path550" class="st0" d="M96.3,91.6c-0.2-4.2,0.3-9.7,4-12.7"/>
<path id="path552" class="st0" d="M98.3,91.6c-0.2-3.5,0.1-8.5,3.4-11.2"/>
<path id="path554" class="st0" d="M100.3,91.6c-0.1-2.8,0-7.3,2.7-9.6"/>
<path id="path556" class="st0" d="M102.4,91.6c-0.1-2.1-0.1-6.1,2.1-8"/>
<path id="path558" class="st0" d="M104.7,87.3c0.2-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.2-2.1"/>
<path id="path560" class="st0" d="M104.4,91.6c0-0.8,0-1.6,0-2.3"/>
<path id="path562" class="st0" d="M106.6,87.9c0.1-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.6-1.1"/>
<path id="path564" class="st0" d="M106.5,91.6c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8"/>
<path id="path566" class="st0" d="M108.5,91.6c0,0-0.5-2.6,0.2-3.3"/></g> </svg>
```

Comment: You can wrap it all in a group and get the bounding box of that group. This will give you the values to be used for a new viewBox. You can use `width="85mm"
   viewBox="-43 28 46 25">` Do not forget to remove the height attribute.

Comment: Is changing the viewbox the only option I have? I need to position and stick within the 85x85mm SVG "canvas" and possibly also stick to adjusting my transforms on the <g> element -only. May I ask how you came to the values posted?

Comment: No. You can use a different transformation for example a rotation around a different center. As I've commented above you need to know the bounding box of the group. You can get it in JavaScript with the getBBox method

Comment: Are you trying to do it manually, or at runtime with JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a reference to an SVG element, you can call `getBBox()` on it. That will return the bounding box of the element and its contents.  However that bounding box *does not include any transform that is applied to that element*.

For example if we call `getBBox()` on your group:

```
document.querySelect("."svg-merge-item-wrapper"").getBBox();
// returns {x: 70.88888549804688,
//          y: 28.600000381469727,
//          width: 99.08346557617188,
//          height: 183.74867248535156}
```

If we want the bounds of the transformed group, we need to call `getBBox()` on an element that contains that transformed group.

```
<g><!-- <=== wrapper group -->
  <g class="svg-merge-item-wrapper" transform="scale(0.25) rotate(90 42.5 42.5) translate(42.5 42.5)">
  ...all the other elements...
  </g>
</g>

document.querySelect("."svg-merge-item-wrapper"").parentElement.getBBox();
// returns {x: -42.4621696472168,
//          y: 28.34722137451172,
//          width: 45.93716812133789,
//          height: 24.77086639404297}
```

... which are the real bounds of the group.

To centre the group in your SVG viewBox, it's just a simple bit of arithmetic to work out how much the group needs to be moved.

dx = newX - oldX
newX = (svgWidth - groupWidth) / 2 = (85 - 45.937) / 2 = 19.53
dx = 19.53 - (-42.46) = **61.99**

dy = (svgHeight - groupHeight) / 2 - oldY
dy = (85 - 24.77) / 2 - 28.35 = **1.77**

So to centre the group we need to add the transform: `translate(61.99 1.77)`.

We can either add that to our temporary wrapping group. Or, if we don't want to keep that, just add it to the **front** (ie. first) of the existing group transform.

```
<g class="svg-merge-item-wrapper" transform="translate(61.99 1.77) scale(0.25) rotate(90 42.5 42.5) translate(42.5 42.5)">
```

I've done it manually here. But obviously this could also be easily done at run-time with JS.

**Demo**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="85mm"
   height="85mm"
   viewBox="0 0 85 85">
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- TRANSFORMATION HERE-->
  <g class="svg-merge-item-wrapper" transform="translate(61.99 1.77) scale(0.25) rotate(90 42.5 42.5) translate(42.5 42.5)">
  <!-- TRANSFORMATION HERE-->
  
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.375;stroke-miterlimit:3.9892;}
</style>
<path id="path6" class="st0" d="M119.2,35.9c0,0,11.2,0,15,7.4c3.8,7.4,4.2,17.8,4.5,19.2c0.3,1.4,0.3,6.3,6,10.8
    c5.6,4.5,6.3,18.5,6.3,18.5s1.4,0,1.4,1.7v5.2c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1c0,0,0,18.5-0.4,28.7c-0.4,10.1-4.2,43-6,50
    c-1.8,7-10.5,31.9-10.5,31.9h-29.7c0,0-9.4-21.7-11.9-36.4s-5.3-24.8-5.6-39.5c-0.3-14.7,0-34.6,0-34.6s-2.1,0.3-2.1-1.4v-5.6
    c0-0.8,0.6-1.4,1.3-1.4c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0-12.6,4.5-16.8c4.5-4.2,6-8,6.3-9.4c0.3-1.4,0.7-7.7,0.7-7.7c1.6-2.2,2.7-4.7,3.1-7.3
    c0.7-4.2,1.1-5.6,1.1-5.6s2.8-6,5.9-7c1.7-0.6,3.5-1,5.3-1.4C115.4,36.1,117.3,35.9,119.2,35.9z"/>
<path id="path8" class="st0" d="M88.4,91.5v-0.3c0,0,0-12.1,4.3-16.1c4.3-4,5.7-7.7,6-9.1c0.2-0.9,0.4-3.9,0.6-5.8
    c0.1-1,0.4-2,0.9-2.8c1.1-1.8,1.8-3.8,2.2-5.9c0.7-4,1-5.4,1-5.4s2.7-5.7,5.6-6.7c1.6-0.6,3.3-1,5-1.3c1.8-0.2,3.5-0.3,5.3-0.3
    c0,0,10.6,0,14.3,7.1c3.7,7.1,3.7,17.5,4.1,18.8c0.4,4,2.4,7.7,5.6,10.1c5.3,4.4,6.3,17.8,6.3,17.8v0.3"/>
<path id="path10" class="st0" d="M98.2,57.6c0,0-10.5-15-15.7-17.5s-11.9-4.5-10.8-6.6c0,0,7-2.1,18.5,4.5s12.1,7.4,12.1,7.4"/>
<path id="path12" class="st0" d="M107,38.4c0,0-0.1-1.8-1.5-1.8c-1.4,0-2.4,1-5.6,0c-3.2-1-3.1-1.4-3.5-1.4
    c-0.3,0-14.3-6.6-18.2-6.6s-6.3,0-7,2.1c-0.7,2.1,0,2.7,0,2.7l0.3,0.1"/>
<circle id="circle14" class="st0" cx="112.2" cy="44.3" r="1.4"/>
<circle id="circle16" class="st0" cx="111.8" cy="44" r="0.7"/>
<line id="line18" class="st0" x1="86.6" y1="91.5" x2="151" y2="91.9"/>
<line id="line20" class="st0" x1="151.3" y1="99.9" x2="87.3" y2="99.9"/>
<path id="path22" class="st0" d="M151.2,118.6c0,0,1.5,0.5,1.5-1.6v-9.8c0,0-0.3-2.1,3.8-1.4c4.2,0.7,9.4,2.1,10.8,8.4
    c0.8,3.8,1,7.7,0.8,11.6c-0.1,1.6-0.2,3.2-0.5,4.8c-1,5.3-3.1,16.6-7.5,24.5c-4.1,7.2-13.5,20.9-17.5,30.9"/>
<path id="path24" class="st0" d="M151.3,104.8c0,0,2-1.4,5.9-0.6c4.2,0.9,10.1,2.4,11.8,9.6c1.6,6.5,0.9,11.6,0.2,16.7
    c-0.7,4.7-1.7,9.3-3.1,13.8c-0.9,2.9-3.4,9.8-5.8,13.6c-1.3,2-13.6,21.7-16.1,27.9s-3.5,8-3.5,16.8c0,7.3,2.8,7.7,2.8,7.7h-2.1
    c0,0-4.6-6.2-1.1-17.2"/>
<path id="path26" class="st0" d="M113.2,105.1h11.5c4.6,5.4,5.2,13.1,1.7,19.2c-6,10.8-6.3,7.3-7,16.8c-0.6,7.9,1.5,17,2.2,19.8
    c0.3,1,0.3,2,0.2,3c-0.3,2.3-1.9,4.7-8-1.4c-7.7-7.7-8.6-23.2-8.7-27.8c0-0.8,0.1-1.7,0.2-2.5c0.9-4.3,2.4-8.5,4.3-12.4
    C112.9,113.9,113.2,105.5,113.2,105.1z"/>
<path id="path28" class="st0" d="M104.8,210.4H93.7c-0.4,0.3-0.5,1-0.2,1.4c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.3c1.4,0.7,51.7-0.3,51.7-0.3
    c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4h-11.2"/>
<polyline id="polyline30" class="st0" points="113.1,106.9 125.8,106.9 126,106.8 "/>
<line id="line32" class="st0" x1="118" y1="165.8" x2="121.1" y2="165.8"/>
<line id="line34" class="st0" x1="116.6" y1="164.8" x2="121.7" y2="164.8"/>
<line id="line36" class="st0" x1="121.9" y1="163.9" x2="115.5" y2="163.9"/>
<line id="line38" class="st0" x1="114.5" y1="163.1" x2="122" y2="163.1"/>
<line id="line40" class="st0" x1="122" y1="162.1" x2="113.6" y2="162.1"/>
<line id="line42" class="st0" x1="112.6" y1="161" x2="121.7" y2="161"/>
<polyline id="polyline44" class="st0" points="112.9,108.5 126.9,108.5 127,108.5 "/>
<polyline id="polyline46" class="st0" points="112.6,110.1 127.5,110.1 127.6,110.1 "/>
<polyline id="polyline48" class="st0" points="112.4,111.6 127.9,111.6 128.1,111.6 "/>
<line id="line50" class="st0" x1="111.6" y1="114.8" x2="128.7" y2="114.8"/>
<line id="line52" class="st0" x1="128.8" y1="116.4" x2="111.2" y2="116.4"/>
<line id="line54" class="st0" x1="110.5" y1="118.3" x2="114.6" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line56" class="st0" x1="115" y1="118.3" x2="116" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line58" class="st0" x1="117" y1="118.3" x2="125.5" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line60" class="st0" x1="125.8" y1="118.3" x2="128.6" y2="118.3"/>
<line id="line62" class="st0" x1="114.2" y1="120.3" x2="115.2" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line64" class="st0" x1="116.2" y1="120.3" x2="121.3" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line66" class="st0" x1="122.1" y1="120.3" x2="124.1" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line68" class="st0" x1="124.6" y1="120.3" x2="125.8" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line70" class="st0" x1="126.7" y1="120.3" x2="127.5" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line72" class="st0" x1="109.5" y1="120.3" x2="113.6" y2="120.3"/>
<line id="line74" class="st0" x1="106.6" y1="127.7" x2="124.6" y2="127.7"/>
<polyline id="polyline76" class="st0" points="128.5,113.2 128.2,113.2 112,113.2 "/>
<ellipse id="ellipse78" class="st0" cx="113.4" cy="44.7" rx="4.7" ry="3.8"/>
<path id="path80" class="st0" d="M123.4,125.9l2.2,0.1"/>
<path id="path82" class="st0" d="M119.3,125.8h2.4"/>
<path id="path84" class="st0" d="M116.4,125.8h1.5"/>
<path id="path86" class="st0" d="M112.5,125.9h2.4"/>
<path id="path88" class="st0" d="M109.6,125.9h1.4"/>
<path id="path90" class="st0" d="M107.2,125.9h1.1"/>
<path id="path92" class="st0" d="M107.5,129.4h-1.3"/>
<path id="path94" class="st0" d="M110.6,129.3h-1.8"/>
<path id="path96" class="st0" d="M116.1,129.3h-4.1"/>
<path id="path98" class="st0" d="M123.6,129.4c-2,0-4-0.1-6.1-0.1"/>
<line id="line100" class="st0" x1="105.7" y1="131.1" x2="122.4" y2="131.1"/>
<path id="path102" class="st0" d="M107.5,132.8h-2.1"/>
<path id="path104" class="st0" d="M113.7,132.8h-4.9"/>
<path id="path106" class="st0" d="M121.3,132.8h-6.2"/>
<path id="path108" class="st0" d="M107.7,134.5h-2.5"/>
<path id="path110" class="st0" d="M114.4,134.5h-5.3"/>
<path id="path112" class="st0" d="M120.5,134.5h-4.6"/>
<line id="line114" class="st0" x1="105.2" y1="136.2" x2="120" y2="136.2"/>
<path id="path116" class="st0" d="M117.2,137.9h2.6"/>
<path id="path118" class="st0" d="M111.7,137.9h3.8"/>
<path id="path120" class="st0" d="M105.3,137.9h5"/>
<line id="line122" class="st0" x1="119.7" y1="139.3" x2="105.4" y2="139.3"/>
<line id="line124" class="st0" x1="105.6" y1="140.7" x2="119.6" y2="140.7"/>
<line id="line126" class="st0" x1="119.5" y1="141.9" x2="105.8" y2="141.9"/>
<line id="line128" class="st0" x1="105.9" y1="143.2" x2="119.4" y2="143.2"/>
<line id="line130" class="st0" x1="119.4" y1="144.4" x2="106.1" y2="144.4"/>
<path id="path132" class="st0" d="M114.1,145.6h5.4"/>
<path id="path134" class="st0" d="M109.4,145.6h2.9"/>
<path id="path136" class="st0" d="M106.3,145.7h1.8"/>
<line id="line138" class="st0" x1="111.7" y1="159.8" x2="121.4" y2="159.7"/>
<line id="line140" class="st0" x1="121.2" y1="158.5" x2="110.9" y2="158.5"/>
<line id="line142" class="st0" x1="110.2" y1="157.3" x2="120.9" y2="157.3"/>
<line id="line144" class="st0" x1="109.6" y1="156.2" x2="120.7" y2="156.2"/>
<line id="line146" class="st0" x1="109.1" y1="154.9" x2="120.4" y2="154.9"/>
<line id="line148" class="st0" x1="120.2" y1="153.5" x2="108.5" y2="153.5"/>
<line id="line150" class="st0" x1="107.9" y1="152" x2="120" y2="152"/>
<line id="line152" class="st0" x1="107.6" y1="150.7" x2="119.8" y2="150.7"/>
<line id="line154" class="st0" x1="119.7" y1="149.2" x2="107.1" y2="149.2"/>
<path id="path156" class="st0" d="M115.5,148h4.1"/>
<path id="path158" class="st0" d="M110.7,148h3.3"/>
<path id="path160" class="st0" d="M106.8,148h2.4"/>
<line id="line162" class="st0" x1="119.5" y1="146.8" x2="106.6" y2="146.8"/>
<path id="path164" class="st0" d="M114.3,92.7h1.7"/>
<path id="path166" class="st0" d="M106.3,92.6c2.1,0,4.2,0,6.3,0"/>
<path id="path168" class="st0" d="M98.2,92.6h6.6"/>
<path id="path170" class="st0" d="M91.7,92.7l4.9-0.1"/>
<path id="path172" class="st0" d="M85.3,92.7h5"/>
<path id="path174" class="st0" d="M130,92.7h-5"/>
<path id="path176" class="st0" d="M136.5,92.6l-4.8,0.1"/>
<path id="path178" class="st0" d="M137.8,92.6c4.7,0,9.5,0,14.2,0.1h0.2"/>
<line id="line180" class="st0" x1="86.6" y1="99.9" x2="86.6" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line182" class="st0" x1="88.9" y1="99.9" x2="88.9" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line184" class="st0" x1="91.1" y1="99.9" x2="91.1" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path186" class="st0" d="M93.3,94.3v-1.1"/>
<path id="path188" class="st0" d="M93.3,99.9v-4.4"/>
<path id="path190" class="st0" d="M95.6,95.4v-2.1"/>
<path id="path192" class="st0" d="M95.6,99.9v-3"/>
<line id="line194" class="st0" x1="97.8" y1="99.9" x2="97.8" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line196" class="st0" x1="100" y1="99.9" x2="100" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line198" class="st0" x1="102.2" y1="99.9" x2="102.2" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path200" class="st0" d="M104.5,94.7v-1.5"/>
<path id="path202" class="st0" d="M104.5,99.9V96"/>
<path id="path204" class="st0" d="M106.7,95.2v-1.9"/>
<path id="path206" class="st0" d="M106.7,99.9v-3"/>
<path id="path208" class="st0" d="M108.9,94.7v-1.5"/>
<path id="path210" class="st0" d="M108.9,97.5v-1.7"/>
<path id="path212" class="st0" d="M108.9,99.9v-1.2"/>
<path id="path214" class="st0" d="M111.1,94.3v-1.1"/>
<path id="path216" class="st0" d="M111.1,99.6v-1.1"/>
<path id="path218" class="st0" d="M126.9,94.8v-1.6"/>
<path id="path220" class="st0" d="M126.9,99.9v-1.6"/>
<path id="path222" class="st0" d="M129.1,94.5v-1.3"/>
<path id="path224" class="st0" d="M129.1,97.3v-1.2"/>
<path id="path226" class="st0" d="M129.1,99.9v-1.4"/>
<path id="path228" class="st0" d="M131.3,94.4v-1.2"/>
<path id="path230" class="st0" d="M131.3,96.9v-1.2"/>
<path id="path232" class="st0" d="M131.3,99.9v-1.8"/>
<path id="path234" class="st0" d="M133.5,94.8v-1.6"/>
<path id="path236" class="st0" d="M133.5,99.9v-2.6"/>
<path id="path238" class="st0" d="M135.7,94.5v-1.3"/>
<path id="path240" class="st0" d="M135.7,96.8v-1.2"/>
<path id="path242" class="st0" d="M135.7,99.9V98"/>
<path id="path244" class="st0" d="M138,95.1v-1.8"/>
<path id="path246" class="st0" d="M138,99.9v-3.6"/>
<line id="line248" class="st0" x1="140.2" y1="99.9" x2="140.2" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line250" class="st0" x1="142.4" y1="99.9" x2="142.4" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line252" class="st0" x1="144.6" y1="99.9" x2="144.6" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line254" class="st0" x1="146.9" y1="99.9" x2="146.9" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line256" class="st0" x1="149.1" y1="99.9" x2="149.1" y2="93.3"/>
<line id="line258" class="st0" x1="151" y1="99.9" x2="151" y2="93.3"/>
<path id="path260" class="st0" d="M142.3,211.3c1.2,0,2.4,0,3.7,0.1"/>
<path id="path262" class="st0" d="M136.5,211.4h2.9"/>
<path id="path264" class="st0" d="M131.9,211.5l3.4-0.1"/>
<path id="path266" class="st0" d="M111.2,211.8c1.9,0,3.7,0,5.6,0"/>
<path id="path268" class="st0" d="M93.5,211.8h13"/>
<path id="path270" class="st0" d="M114.8,47.7c1.7-0.3,2.9-2,2.6-3.7"/>
<path id="path272" class="st0" d="M112.2,47.8c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0"/>
<path id="path274" class="st0" d="M71,32.1c0,0,11.2-1.5,19.4,6"/>
<path id="path276" class="st0" d="M106.5,37.1c-2.3,1-3.6,3.4-3.2,5.9"/>
<path id="path278" class="st0" d="M79.8,28.8c0,0,16,6.4,17.7,7.5c1.7,1.1,4.9,1.7,6,1.4c0.8-0.2,1.6-0.4,2.5-0.4"/>
<path id="path280" class="st0" d="M75.4,28.6c3.5,0.7,6.9,1.9,10.2,3.5c4.9,2.5,11.5,5.2,11.5,5.2s4.5,2.1,6,1.4
    c1.4-0.7,1.8-0.6,1.8-0.6"/>
<path id="path282" class="st0" d="M72.5,29.2c0,0,2.9-0.3,7.8,1.8c4.9,2.1,16.8,7.7,16.8,7.7s4.2,1.8,5.2,1.1
    c0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.7-0.7"/>
<path id="path284" class="st0" d="M81,32.3c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.4,1.8,0.5"/>
<path id="path286" class="st0" d="M76.9,30.9c1,0.3,2,0.7,3,1.1"/>
<path id="path288" class="st0" d="M71.5,30.3c1.4-0.3,2.9-0.3,4.3,0.2"/>
<path id="path290" class="st0" d="M71.6,34.4c0,0,9.4,2.9,12.6,5.7c3.1,2.8,14.8,15.1,14.5,16.7"/>
<path id="path292" class="st0" d="M99.6,55.3c0,0-13-15.5-17.5-17.6c-4.6-2.1-9.8-4.3-9.8-4.3"/>
<path id="path294" class="st0" d="M88.7,41.6c4.2,3.8,7.8,8.3,11.5,12.6"/>
<path id="path296" class="st0" d="M83.9,37.9c0.9,0.6,1.7,1.2,2.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path298" class="st0" d="M81.4,36.3c0.5,0.3,1,0.5,1.4,0.8"/>
<path id="path300" class="st0" d="M74.9,33.2c1.1,0.5,2.1,1,3.2,1.5"/>
<path id="path302" class="st0" d="M91.8,43.5c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.3-1.2"/>
<path id="path304" class="st0" d="M95.1,46.9c-0.8-0.9-1.6-1.7-2.4-2.6"/>
<path id="path306" class="st0" d="M97.8,49.8l-1.1-1.2"/>
<path id="path308" class="st0" d="M100.6,52.9l-2.1-2.3"/>
<path id="path310" class="st0" d="M106.8,37.6c0,0-2.8,1.5-2.7,4.1"/>
<polyline id="polyline312" class="st0" points="124.1,99.9 124.1,103.8 124.1,105.1 "/>
<line id="line314" class="st0" x1="127.2" y1="99.9" x2="127.2" y2="109.3"/>
<path id="path316" class="st0" d="M123,150.1c0,1,0,1.9,0,2.9"/>
<path id="path318" class="st0" d="M123.1,146.3c0,0.8-0.1,1.6-0.1,2.4"/>
<path id="path320" class="st0" d="M123.3,142.7c0,0.6,0,1.1-0.1,1.7"/>
<path id="path322" class="st0" d="M123.6,135.6c-0.1,1.7-0.2,3.3-0.3,5"/>
<path id="path324" class="st0" d="M123.9,128.8l-0.2,5.5"/>
<path id="path326" class="st0" d="M124.9,169.2c0,0.6-0.1,1.1-0.2,1.7"/>
<path id="path328" class="st0" d="M125.2,165.8c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.1,1.4"/>
<path id="path330" class="st0" d="M125.5,161.2c0,0.6-0.1,1.1-0.1,1.7"/>
<path id="path332" class="st0" d="M125.8,155.6c0,1.1-0.1,2.3-0.2,3.4"/>
<path id="path334" class="st0" d="M126.1,148.6c0,1-0.1,2.1-0.2,3.1"/>
<path id="path336" class="st0" d="M126.7,139.7c-0.2,2-0.3,4-0.4,6"/>
<path id="path338" class="st0" d="M126.8,135.3c0,1,0,2-0.1,2.9"/>
<path id="path340" class="st0" d="M127,123.5c-0.1,3.3-0.1,6.5-0.1,10.1"/>
<path id="path342" class="st0" d="M124.8,180.5c-0.1,0.6-0.3,1.3-0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path344" class="st0" d="M125.6,177.2c-0.1,0.6-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path346" class="st0" d="M128,159.2c-0.6,5.7-1.3,11.3-2.3,17"/>
<path id="path348" class="st0" d="M130.3,99.9c-0.2,14.5-0.3,29-1.1,43.5c-0.2,4.1-0.5,8.3-0.9,12.4"/>
<path id="path350" class="st0" d="M125.4,185c-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.5-0.6,2.3"/>
<path id="path352" class="st0" d="M126.8,180.5c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.9-0.9,2.8"/>
<path id="path354" class="st0" d="M129.1,167.6c-0.4,3.8-1.1,7.6-2,11.4"/>
<path id="path356" class="st0" d="M132.1,99.9c0,21.7,0,43.3-2.7,64.8"/>
<path id="path358" class="st0" d="M126.2,189.9c-0.1,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.4,1.6"/>
<path id="path360" class="st0" d="M127.1,186.4c-0.1,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path362" class="st0" d="M129.7,173.7c-0.5,3.1-1.1,6.1-1.8,9.2"/>
<path id="path364" class="st0" d="M133.9,99.9c-0.4,23.1-0.8,46.1-3.5,69.1"/>
<path id="path366" class="st0" d="M127.3,192.5c-0.2,1-0.5,2.1-0.8,3.1"/>
<path id="path368" class="st0" d="M135.7,99.9c-0.5,30.4-0.8,61.2-8,90.8"/>
<path id="path370" class="st0" d="M127.1,198c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.3,1.2"/>
<path id="path372" class="st0" d="M128,194.8c-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4"/>
<path id="path374" class="st0" d="M137.5,99.9c-0.9,31.1-0.5,62.6-9,92.5"/>
<path id="path376" class="st0" d="M128.7,197.7c-0.3,1.1-0.5,2.1-0.8,3.2"/>
<path id="path378" class="st0" d="M139.3,99.9c-0.6,16.1,0.1,32.2-2,48.6v3.5c-1.4,15-3.8,30.1-8.2,44.2"/>
<path id="path380" class="st0" d="M141.2,99.9c0,0-0.3,25.4-1,37.3c-0.6,9.1-2.7,31.8-5.3,42.3c-2.2,8.6-6,21.9-6.6,24.3"/>
<path id="path382" class="st0" d="M143,99.9c0,0-0.4,27.2-1.1,38c-0.6,8.6-3,32.8-5.8,43c-2.4,8.8-7.4,25.1-7.8,27"/>
<path id="path384" class="st0" d="M144.8,99.9c0,0-0.4,28.9-1.2,38.7c-0.6,8.1-3.3,33.8-6.3,43.8c-2.7,9-6.3,20.9-6.7,22.4l-1.7,5.5
    "/>
<path id="path386" class="st0" d="M146.6,99.9c0,0-0.5,30.7-1.2,39.5c-0.6,7.6-3.6,34.7-6.7,44.6c-3,9.1-6.9,21.8-7.1,22.7
    c0,0-1,3.3-1.1,3.7"/>
<path id="path388" class="st0" d="M148.4,99.9c0,0-0.6,32.5-1.3,40.2c-0.7,7.2-3.9,35.7-7.2,45.4c-3.2,9.3-7.4,22.6-7.5,23.1
    l-0.6,1.8"/>
<path id="path390" class="st0" d="M150.2,99.9c0,0-0.7,34.3-1.4,40.9c-0.7,6.6-4.2,36.7-7.7,46.1c-3.5,9.4-8,23.4-8,23.4"/>
<path id="path392" class="st0" d="M114.2,180.4c0.1,0.6,0.3,1.2,0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path394" class="st0" d="M113.5,177.1c0.1,0.6,0.2,1.3,0.4,1.9"/>
<path id="path396" class="st0" d="M111.1,160.1c0.6,5.3,1.3,10.6,2.2,16"/>
<path id="path398" class="st0" d="M108.7,99.9c0.1,6.8,0.2,13.5,0.4,20.3"/>
<path id="path400" class="st0" d="M113.6,184.9c0.2,0.8,0.4,1.5,0.6,2.3"/>
<path id="path402" class="st0" d="M112.3,180.4c0.3,0.9,0.5,1.9,0.9,2.8"/>
<path id="path404" class="st0" d="M109.9,167.5c0.4,3.8,1.1,7.6,2,11.4"/>
<path id="path406" class="st0" d="M108.5,154.3c0.3,3.5,0.7,6.9,1.1,10.4"/>
<path id="path408" class="st0" d="M106.6,99.9c0,8.6,0.4,17,0.5,25.6"/>
<path id="path410" class="st0" d="M112.8,189.8c0.1,0.5,0.3,1.1,0.4,1.6c0,0,1,5,1.4,7.1"/>
<path id="path412" class="st0" d="M112,186.3c0.1,0.6,0.3,1.2,0.5,1.9"/>
<path id="path414" class="st0" d="M109.3,173.6c0.5,3.1,1.1,6.1,1.8,9.2"/>
<path id="path416" class="st0" d="M106.8,148.3c0.5,6.9,1.1,13.7,1.9,20.5"/>
<path id="path418" class="st0" d="M104.8,99.9c0.2,9.6,0.6,19.2,0.9,28.8"/>
<path id="path420" class="st0" d="M111.7,192.4c0.2,1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.1"/>
<path id="path422" class="st0" d="M103.1,99.9c0.5,30.4,1,61.1,8.2,90.8"/>
<path id="path424" class="st0" d="M111.9,197.9c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3,1.2c0,0,0.7,2.9,1,4"/>
<path id="path426" class="st0" d="M111.1,194.7l0.3,1.4"/>
<path id="path428" class="st0" d="M101.3,99.9c0.9,31.1,0.7,62.5,9.1,92.4"/>
<path id="path430" class="st0" d="M110.3,197.6c0.3,1.1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.2c0,0,1.7,6,2.1,6.4"/>
<path id="path432" class="st0" d="M99.6,99.9c0.6,16.1,0,32.1,2.1,48.5v3.5c1.4,15.1,3.8,30,8.2,44.2"/>
<path id="path434" class="st0" d="M97.5,99.9c0,0,0.7,25.3,1.4,37.2c0.6,9.1,2.7,31.8,5.3,42.3c2.2,8.6,7.3,27.2,8.3,29.3"/>
<path id="path436" class="st0" d="M96.1,99.9c0,0,0.3,27.1,1.1,37.9c0.6,8.6,3,32.8,5.8,43c2.4,8.8,7.4,25.1,7.8,27"/>
<path id="path438" class="st0" d="M94.3,99.9c0,0,0.3,28.8,1.1,38.6c0.6,8.1,3.3,33.8,6.3,43.8c2.7,9,6.3,20.9,6.7,22.4l1.7,5.5v0.1
    "/>
<path id="path440" class="st0" d="M92.2,99.9c0,0,0.7,30.6,1.4,39.4c0.6,7.6,3.6,34.7,6.7,44.6c3,9.1,6.9,21.8,7.1,22.7
    c0,0,1,3.3,1.1,3.7l0.1,0.1"/>
<path id="path442" class="st0" d="M90.5,99.9c0,0,0.7,32.4,1.4,40.1c0.7,7.1,3.9,35.7,7.2,45.4c3.2,9.3,7.4,22.6,7.5,23.1l0.6,1.8
    l0.1,0.1"/>
<path id="path444" class="st0" d="M88.8,99.9c0,0,0.7,34.2,1.4,40.8c0.7,6.6,4.2,36.7,7.7,46.1s8,23.4,8,23.4"/>
<line id="line446" class="st0" x1="105.8" y1="210.2" x2="105.9" y2="210.4"/>
<path id="path448" class="st0" d="M110.6,110.3c-0.1,1,0,2,0.2,2.9"/>
<path id="path450" class="st0" d="M110.7,105c0,1,0,2.1,0,3.1"/>
<path id="path452" class="st0" d="M110.8,99.9c0,0.9,0,1.8-0.1,2.7"/>
<path id="path454" class="st0" d="M112.5,39.6c1.7-0.4,3.5-0.5,5.2-0.5c0,0,10.8-0.8,14.7,6.6c3.9,7.4,3.5,17.2,3.8,18.5
    c0.3,1.3,0.1,5.5,5.3,9.7s5.9,17.2,5.9,17.2v0.3"/>
<path id="path456" class="st0" d="M118.6,40.4c4.7,0.3,9.1,1.3,11.8,5.4c3.1,4.7,3.9,11.4,4.4,16.8c0.3,3.2,0.8,6.4,2.6,9.1"/>
<path id="path458" class="st0" d="M118.9,42.5c4.3,0.3,8.3,1.3,10.8,5.1c2.9,4.3,3.6,10.5,4,15.5c0.3,2.9,0.7,5.9,2.4,8.4"/>
<path id="path460" class="st0" d="M119.2,44.6c3.9,0.3,7.4,1.2,9.7,4.7c2.6,4,3.3,9.7,3.7,14.2c0.3,2.7,0.7,5.4,2.2,7.7"/>
<path id="path462" class="st0" d="M119.5,46.8c3.4,0.2,6.6,1.2,8.6,4.4c2.3,3.6,2.9,8.8,3.3,13c0.2,2.5,0.6,5,2,7"/>
<path id="path464" class="st0" d="M119.8,48.9c3,0.2,5.8,1.2,7.6,4.1c2,3.3,2.6,7.9,3,11.6c0.1,2.2,0.7,4.4,1.8,6.3"/>
<path id="path466" class="st0" d="M120.1,51.1c2.7,0,5.2,1.5,6.5,3.8c1.7,3,2.2,7.1,2.6,10.4c0.1,2,0.6,3.9,1.6,5.6"/>
<path id="path468" class="st0" d="M124.6,55.1c1.9,1.9,2.6,4.9,3,7.5s0.3,5.8,1.9,8.1"/>
<path id="path470" class="st0" d="M120.4,53.2c0.9,0.1,1.7,0.3,2.5,0.6"/>
<path id="path472" class="st0" d="M127,66.6c0.1,1.4,0.5,2.7,1.2,3.9"/>
<path id="path474" class="st0" d="M120.7,55.3c4.4,0.3,5.5,5.5,6,9.1"/>
<path id="path476" class="st0" d="M121,57.5c1.3,0.1,2.5,1,3.4,2.9c0.8,2.1,1.3,4.3,1.5,6.5c0.1,1.2,0.4,2.4,1.1,3.4"/>
<path id="path478" class="st0" d="M123.7,62.4c0.4,1.3,0.7,2.6,0.9,4c0,1.3,0.4,2.6,1,3.7"/>
<path id="path480" class="st0" d="M121.3,59.6c0.6,0.1,1.1,0.4,1.4,0.9"/>
<path id="path482" class="st0" d="M123.6,67.8c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.5,0.7,2.2"/>
<path id="path484" class="st0" d="M121.6,61.8c1.1,0.4,1.4,3,1.6,4"/>
<path id="path486" class="st0" d="M122.4,67.8c0,0.7,0.3,1.4,0.6,2"/>
<path id="path488" class="st0" d="M122,63.9c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.2,2"/>
<path id="path490" class="st0" d="M141.7,76.1c3.5,4.3,4.3,10.1,4.7,15.5"/>
<path id="path492" class="st0" d="M140.4,77.2c3.2,3.9,4,9.2,4.3,14.4"/>
<path id="path494" class="st0" d="M139.1,78.4c2.9,3.5,3.7,8.3,4,13.3"/>
<path id="path496" class="st0" d="M137.8,79.5c2.6,3.1,3.3,7.5,3.6,12.2"/>
<path id="path498" class="st0" d="M136.5,80.6c2.2,2.7,3,6.6,3.2,11.1"/>
<path id="path500" class="st0" d="M135.2,81.7c1.9,2.4,2.7,5.7,2.8,10"/>
<path id="path502" class="st0" d="M134,82.8c1.6,2,2.4,4.8,2.4,8.9"/>
<path id="path504" class="st0" d="M132.7,83.9c1.3,1.6,2,4,2.1,7.8"/>
<path id="path506" class="st0" d="M132.9,89.2c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.7,0.1,2.5"/>
<path id="path508" class="st0" d="M131.4,85c0.5,0.6,0.8,1.3,1.1,2"/>
<path id="path510" class="st0" d="M130.1,86.2c0.6,0.8,1.4,2.2,1.3,5.6"/>
<path id="path512" class="st0" d="M129.7,90.6c0,0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1"/>
<path id="path514" class="st0" d="M128.8,87.3c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.6,1.3"/>
<path id="path516" class="st0" d="M128.1,90c0,0.6,0,1.2,0,1.7"/>
<path id="path518" class="st0" d="M127.6,88.4c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1"/>
<path id="path520" class="st0" d="M98.2,70.8c0.9-1.3,1.6-2.6,2.1-4.1c0.3-2.4,0-5.2,1-7.7c1.8-4.2,2.5-8.7,3.8-13
    c0.4-1.1,1.1-2.2,2.1-2.9"/>
<path id="path522" class="st0" d="M106.9,46.7c-1,1.7-1.3,3.9-1.8,5.8c-0.5,2.1-1.1,4.2-1.8,6.3c-0.7,2-1.1,4.2-1.2,6.3
    c-0.2,2-0.9,3.9-2,5.6"/>
<path id="path524" class="st0" d="M108,48.6c-1.4,2.4-1.4,5.5-2.1,8.3c-1.4,3.5-1.7,7.3-2.8,11.2c-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-1,2.4"/>
<path id="path526" class="st0" d="M109.7,49.8c-0.6,0.6-1,1.4-1.2,2.3c-0.7,3-1.3,6.6-2.4,9.6c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.5,1.6
    c-0.3,1.4-0.2,2.8-0.4,4.1c-0.2,1.1-0.6,2.1-1.2,3.1"/>
<path id="path528" class="st0" d="M108.5,59.4c-0.4,1.9-1.2,3.7-1.4,5.6c-0.3,1.9-0.2,3.7-1.1,5.3"/>
<path id="path530" class="st0" d="M110.5,52c-1.2,1-1.2,3.6-1.5,5"/>
<path id="path532" class="st0" d="M111.3,54.3c-0.4,0.5-0.6,1.2-0.6,1.8c-0.3,2.5-0.8,4.9-1.4,7.4c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.3,1.2
    c-0.2,1-0.4,2.1-0.4,3.1c-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.6-0.5,2.4"/>
<path id="path534" class="st0" d="M111.5,60.7c-1,2.9-1,6-1.6,9.3"/>
<path id="path536" class="st0" d="M112.1,56.4c-0.3,0.7-0.4,1.5-0.4,2.3"/>
<path id="path538" class="st0" d="M111.8,67.7c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.5,0,2.2"/>
<path id="path540" class="st0" d="M112.7,62.7c-0.1,1-0.3,2-0.5,3"/>
<path id="path542" class="st0" d="M112.9,58.7c0,0.7,0,1.3,0,2"/>
<path id="path544" class="st0" d="M90.2,91.5C89.8,85.2,90.8,78.2,96,74"/>
<path id="path546" class="st0" d="M92.2,91.5c-0.3-5.6,0.6-12.1,5.3-15.9"/>
<path id="path548" class="st0" d="M94.2,91.5c-0.3-4.9,0.4-10.9,4.6-14.3"/>
<path id="path550" class="st0" d="M96.3,91.6c-0.2-4.2,0.3-9.7,4-12.7"/>
<path id="path552" class="st0" d="M98.3,91.6c-0.2-3.5,0.1-8.5,3.4-11.2"/>
<path id="path554" class="st0" d="M100.3,91.6c-0.1-2.8,0-7.3,2.7-9.6"/>
<path id="path556" class="st0" d="M102.4,91.6c-0.1-2.1-0.1-6.1,2.1-8"/>
<path id="path558" class="st0" d="M104.7,87.3c0.2-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.2-2.1"/>
<path id="path560" class="st0" d="M104.4,91.6c0-0.8,0-1.6,0-2.3"/>
<path id="path562" class="st0" d="M106.6,87.9c0.1-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.6-1.1"/>
<path id="path564" class="st0" d="M106.5,91.6c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8"/>
<path id="path566" class="st0" d="M108.5,91.6c0,0-0.5-2.6,0.2-3.3"/></g>
</svg>
```